# What makes a "Hot meta post"?

Tags: discussion, meta

I am just curious if anyone knows really, what are the criteria for the "Hot meta posts" in the side bar.

I guess it is automatic but what is it based on? Views? Votes? Activity?

I noticed downvoted questions never get on there, even if they are very active.

So, what makes a Hot Meta Post?

Comment: Now this question is displaying in _"Hot Meta Posts"_   :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/270345)

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked
>     [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the
>     past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of
>     these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length
>     over 4. (Note that the timing and tags [can be adjusted
>     per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)